# How to use pull to refresh in a FlatList with centerContent set to true (React Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I've been trying to make a FlatList work with centered content but there is a problem.

When I set the property `centerContent` (from ScrollView) to `true` the scroll does not work because the content is smaller than the ScrollView.

Can you think of any way to keep the pull to refresh working when the content is centered and small?